# How to print all the console errors to an html file as soon as the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to see all the console error messages in an html file as soon as the page loads, I am new to JS, so don't know much

Comment: is this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763361/get-console-history